# Inheritance with two abstract classes

Tags: java

Im trying to create an arraylist that contains at least two instances of each class,  I need to achieve this using a single arraylist. The problem is the class HourlyWorker and ContractWorker both implement the abstract class Smarty where the Class Hobbit implements the abstract class Simpleton and i cant figure out how to use both in one arraylist.

```
public class MainClass {

private ArrayList<Smarty> list;

    public MainClass() {
        list = new ArrayList<Smarty>();
        list.add(new HourlyWorker("Bob", 50, 40, 8.0));
        list.add(new HourlyWorker("Bill", 70, 50, 12.0));
        list.add(new ContractWorker("Jill", 80, 8, 100.0));
        list.add(new ContractWorker("Amy", 125, 12, 85.0));
        list.add(new Hobbit("Frodo", 12));
        list.add(new Hobbit("Merry", 8));
    }
```

The part that doesnt work is

```
list.add(new Hobbit("Frodo", 12));
list.add(new Hobbit("Merry", 8));
```

Also the abstract class Smarty implements Simpleton

all my classes

abstract class Smarty

```
public abstract class Smarty extends Simpleton {
    private int IQ;
    public Smarty(){

    }

    public Smarty(String name, int IQ) {
        setFirstName(name);
        this.IQ = IQ;
    }

    public Smarty(int IQ){
        this();
        this.IQ = IQ;
    }

    public int getIQ(){
        return IQ;
    }
    public void setIQ(int IQ){
        this.IQ = IQ;
    }

    public abstract double getIncome();

}
```

abstract class Simpleton

```
public abstract class Simpleton {
    private String name;
    public Simpleton(){

    }
    public Simpleton(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public abstract String getName();

    public abstract String doMath();

    public abstract String saySomethingSmart();
}
```

class HourlyWorker

```
public class HourlyWorker extends Smarty{
private int hoursWorked;
private double hourlyPay;

public HourlyWorker(String name,int IQ, int hoursWorked, double hourlyPay){
    super(IQ);
    setFirstName(name);
    setHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
    this.hourlyPay = hourlyPay;
}

public int getHoursWorked(){
    return hoursWorked;
}
public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked){
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}
public double getHourlyPay(){
    return hourlyPay;
}
public void setHourlyPay(double hourlyPay){
    this.hourlyPay = hourlyPay;
}
public String multiply(int x, int y){
    return x + " x " + y + " = " + x * y;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getFirstName();
}

@Override
public String doMath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "I can Multiply! " + multiply(2, 3);
}

@Override
public String saySomethingSmart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Hippos are dangerous!";
}

@Override
public double getIncome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double x = getHoursWorked();
    double y = getHourlyPay();
    double income = x * y;
    return income;
}

}
```

class ContractWorker

```
public class ContractWorker extends Smarty{
private int contractsCompleted;
private double payPerContract;

public ContractWorker(String name,int IQ, int contractsCompleted, double payPerContract) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(IQ);
    setFirstName(name);
    this.contractsCompleted = contractsCompleted;
    this.payPerContract = payPerContract;
}
public int getContractsCompleted(){
    return contractsCompleted;
}
public void setContractsCompleted(int contractsCompleted){
    this.contractsCompleted = contractsCompleted;
}
public double getPayPerContract(){
    return payPerContract;
}
public void setPayPerContract(double payPerContract){
    this.payPerContract = payPerContract;
}
public String division(int x, int y){
    return x + " / " + y + " = " + x/y;
}

public double getIncome() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double x = getContractsCompleted();
    double y = getPayPerContract();
    double income = x*y;
    return income;
}
@Override
public String doMath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ": I can do division! " + division(10,2);
}
@Override
public String saySomethingSmart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ": The stars are aligned tonight.";
}
@Override
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getFirstName();
}

}
```

class Hobbit

```
public class Hobbit extends Simpleton{
private int carrots;

public Hobbit(String name, int carrots){
    super(name);
    this.carrots = carrots;
}
public int getCarrotsPicked(){
    return carrots;
}
public void setCarrotsPicked(int carrots){
    this.carrots = carrots;
}
public String add(int x, int y){
    return x + " + " + y + " = " + x+y;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getFirstName();
}

@Override
public String doMath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "I can add! " + add(2,2);
}

@Override
public String saySomethingSmart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Leave me alone Sam!";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because the class Hobbit is does not implement the abstract class Smarty.

You say "the class HourlyWorker and ContractWorker both implement the abstract class Smarty where the Class Hobbit implements the abstract class Simpleton" and that Smarty implements Simpleton.

The problem is easy to see when you create a tree:

`Simpleton
                /        \
            Smarty       Hobbit
           /      \ 
     HourlyWorker ContractWorker`

As you can see, Hobbit does not implement abstract class Smarty.

So, when you create an ArrayList of Smarty objects, you cannot put in a Hobbit object because it is not a Smarty.

Instead, make your ArrayList contain Simpleton objects instead. Your three non-abstract classes are all children of Simpleton, so you can put it in a Simpleton ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Simpleton> list = new ArrayList<Simpleton>();
```

Then, your adding operations should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, after looking at your tree it all clicked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make your list contain objects of type `Simpleton` since this is the shared parent of all the objects you want to store in the list:

```
public MainClass() {
    list = new ArrayList<Simpleton>();
    list.add(new HourlyWorker("Bob", 50, 40, 8.0));
    list.add(new HourlyWorker("Bill", 70, 50, 12.0));
    list.add(new ContractWorker("Jill", 80, 8, 100.0));
    list.add(new ContractWorker("Amy", 125, 12, 85.0));
    list.add(new Hobbit("Frodo", 12));
    list.add(new Hobbit("Merry", 8));
}
```